# Listview vs. Recycleview and Scrollview changes in Kivy 1.10

Tags: python, python-2.7, listview, scrollview, kivy

I've upgraded to Kivy 1.10, and so I figured that I should change all of my ListViews over to RecycleViews. However, I'm noticing that dealing with selections is slightly more difficult than before. To start with, I tried replicating what I had with the `SelectableLabel` and `SelectableRecycleBoxLayout` from `kivy/uix/recycleview/__init__.py`. However, I noticed a strange behaviour with the selections. I have 2 RecycleViews `listview1` and `listview2` as below.

```
RecycleView:
    id: listview1
    size_hint: 5./16, 25*8./600
    pos: 398-self.width, 600*0.49
    viewclass: 'SelectableLabel'
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 1, 1, 1, 1
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
    SelectableRecycleBoxLayout:
        color: [0, 0, 0, 1]
        colourS: (0.76,0.87,1,1)
        colourU: (1, 1, 1, 1)
        default_size: None, 25#dp(56)
        default_size_hint: 1, None
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height
        orientation: 'vertical'
RecycleView:
    id: listview2
    size_hint: 5./16, 25*8./600
    pos: 402, 600*0.49
    viewclass: 'SelectableLabel'
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 1, 1, 1, 1
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
    SelectableRecycleBoxLayout:
        color: [0, 0, 0, 1]
        colourS: (0.76,0.87,1,1)
        colourU: (1, 1, 1, 1)
        default_size: None, 25#dp(56)
        default_size_hint: 1, None
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height
        orientation: 'vertical'
```

Additionally, I added a `mySelection` variable to `RecycleView` so that I wouldn't have to loop of the data to get selected items, and I made an edit to `SelectableLabel.apply_selection` to facilitate this.

```
def apply_selection(self, rv, index, is_selected):
    ''' Respond to the selection of items in the view. '''
    self.selected = is_selected
    if is_selected:
        rv.mySelection.append(rv.data[index])
    else:
        if rv.data[index] in rv.mySelection:
            rv.mySelection.remove(rv.data[index])
```

It appears that despite the fact that `listview1` and `listview2` have different `data` variables, selecting an item in `listview1` also has it be selected by `listview2`. I'm guessing that this is because both have `SelectableLabel` for their `viewclass`. Would this mean that each `RecycleView` would need it's own distinct `viewclass` to ensure that this crossup doesn't occur?

Additionally, I noticed that scrolling in a Scrollview is much more rigid in Kivy 1.10 than in 1.9. For example, a quick swipe could get from the top of a Scrollview to the bottom, but now the same swipe might move the Scrollview down about 5 lines of text. I'm wondering what I would need to change to recover the behaviour from Kivy 1.9.